# Questions about Windows Phone notification URIs

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, uri, mpns

I would like to ask some questions about Windows Phone push notification Uris, and I would appreciate if someone could answer them.

1. Uris have the same host? I mean, for example if the uri is this:

http://db3.notify.live.net/throttledthirdparty/01.00/AQH1BAJf76f1RY_CHtRmqazsAgAAAAADAQAAAAQUZm52OkRFQkNENjJCNTFENUM0RjQFBkVVTk8wMQ

The host will always be http://db3.notify.live.net/throttledthirdparty/01.00/ ?

1. The token has always the same length? Or same format? Just like this AQH1BAJf76f1RY_CHtRmqazsAgAAAAADAQAAAAQUZm52OkRFQkNENjJCNTFENUM0RjQFBkVVTk8wMQ

Beginning with AQ or ending with wMQ for example.

NOTE: I am talking about Windows Phone device, perhaps it may vary depending on the platform.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft don't supply info regarding the host of the notification channel for MPNS (as opposed to WNS, for Windows 8 Store Applications, in which the host always ends with the `windows.com` domain).

The length of the notification channel is up to 1024 characters. There is no information regarding the specific format.

> When your client app detects a channel URI change, your app must send
>   the newest URI to your service. Your service must retain only the
>   latest channel URI for each client. Consider associating the user’s
>   device ID with their channel URI in your service. Your service can
>   then use the device ID to reconcile whether a channel URI is for a new
>   user, or if it’s replacing an existing channel URI for an existing
>   user.
>
> Windows Phone documentation offers many examples that demonstrate how
>   to set up an app to receive push notifications, including some that
>   show you how you can set up an event handler to respond to changes in
>   the channel URI. See How to Send and receive Tile Notifications for
>   Windows Phone for one way to do this using the
>   PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated function.
>
> Channel URIs may be up to 1,024 characters long.

([Source](https://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/10/22/recommended-practices-for-using-microsoft-push-notification-service-mpns.aspx?Redirected=true))